# .net generic method with params IQueryable<T> and Expression<Func<T, T>>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression, iqueryable

I want to create a generic method for this function and send the user class and where clause like parameters.

```
public void Update(where clause, User user) {}
```

But I cannot find a right way.

```
ctx.Users.Where(x => x.Id == 10)
         .Update(x => new User() { Name = "Jack" });
```

The method declaration is:

```
public static int Update<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, T>> updateFactory) where T : class;
```

Comment: Do you need to pass an already created User instance? Or can you pass an update factory like `x => new User() { Name = "Jack" }`?

Comment: Yes. I pass a instance of User created before.

Comment: Does the `User` class have other properties than `Name`? If so, then should the `Update` method also update other properties? For example, assume there is an `Age` property, should it also be updated? How would the `Update` method know which properties to update?

Comment: Yes the user class have more properties. I set properties before send the object to the function.

Comment: Yes. But which properties should it update? All of them? Please note that once you create the object, there is no way to tell which of them you set and which of them you didn't set. For example, if you have an `int Age` property of value `0`, this could mean that either it was not set during initialization or that it was explicitly set to `0`. Maybe setting `Age` to `0` is what you really want the update to do.

Comment: The properties are read from the database. So they are all filled before.

Comment: So this means that you want to update all the properties/columns?

Comment: There is a way to know which properties have been filled before send the object to the func?

Comment: Only if you pass an expression, not an already created instance.

Comment: Ok is better. I can call the func like this: Update<T>(x => User() { Name = "Jack" })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass an already created `User` instance, the `Update` method would not be able to know which properties to update (e.g. should it update all of them? Or the ones with non-default values? What if a property intentionally was set to a default value?).

You need to pass a `Expression<Func<T, T>>` expression that contains a member initialization expression, e.g. `x => new User() { Name = "Jack" }`.

Expressions are code as data. Internally the framework would parse the expression and see which properties were intended to be updated. In the case of the example, it will see that only the `Name` property was intended to be updated.

As for the where expression, you need to pass `Expression<Func<User,bool>>`. So your method would look like this:

```
public void Update(
    Expression<Func<User,bool>> condition,
    Expression<Func<User,User>> updateFactory)
{
    ctx.Users
       .Where(condition)
       .Update(updateFactory);
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
Update(x => x.Id == 10, x => new User() { Name = "Jack" });
```

**EDIT:**

If you have a way to find which properties to update, you can build the expression like this:

```
public static void Update(
    Expression<Func<User, bool>> condition,
    User user,
    PropertyInfo[] propertiesToUpdate)
{
    Expression<Func<User, User>> updateFactory =
        Expression.Lambda<Func<User, User>>(
            Expression.MemberInit(
                Expression.New(typeof (User)),
                propertiesToUpdate
                    .Select(prop =>
                        Expression.Bind(
                            prop.SetMethod,
                            Expression.Constant(prop.GetValue(user))))),
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "u"));

    ctx.Users
        .Where(condition)
        .Update(updateFactory);
}
```

If you only have property names, you can use the [Type.GetProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy(v=vs.110).aspx) method to obtain the corresponding `PropertyInfo`.

Comment: if I want pass only the object User and use a function for generate the expression how i can do? I want check if properties was set like this: `var entry = _Context.Entry(entity);
            foreach (var property in entry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
            {
                var original = entry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(property);
                var current = entry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(property);
                if (original != null && !original.Equals(current))
                { ---property change attach to expression
                }
            }`

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you can get which properties you want to update, you can build the expression yourself.